# Ethernet Multicast without sending member ship reports

Tags: multicast, lan, ethernet, igmp

this is a homework question.
I tried almost a week for finding a solution for this problem. The problem is as follows

Consider doing a multicast in an Extended Ethernet LAN (multiple Ethernet LAN segments connected via bridges). Assume that hosts do not send Ethernet membership reports (which we discussed in class). However, the bridges (not the hosts) can have their software configured as we please. Assume want to implement IPv4 multicasting on that LAN. How would you modify the bridges to allow efficient multicasting? I.e., bridges forward IP multicast packets only to the LAN segments where there are receivers, and it should involve the least amount of processing at the bridges.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying hosts do not send IGMP membership reports? As I've never heard Ethernet membership reports..

And I'm confused by the requirements. If the hosts cannot send membership reports (assume it's IGMP one), how could the bridges know whether there is any receiver in a LAN segment? IP multicast is receiver driven design, the receivers must indicate their interests in some multicast group.